# facebook visible-to-connection creates mega space on revealed content

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

I'm using the  fbml and all is going well except for the extra space that displays when the page is UN-liked and there is a single image on the page.  Liking the page results in displaying a 2nd image and a full page of content.

The amount of empty space i have to scroll thru to view the 1st (Unliked) image looks like the same amount of space as the entire content of the page when it is Liked.

(am testing this in a second, NON-admin account.) I have tried Liking and Unliking, refreshing, clearing cookies and I continue to see the empty space.

Suggestions anyone..???

Comment: I didn't really get you here, attaching a screenshots and some code will be helpful!

Comment: yeah, i thought it might sound unclear. Here's a pic of what's happening: http://i867.photobucket.com/albums/ab232/v2basic/fanpageemptyspace.jpg  ...and here's a picture of the stripped down code.

Comment: SOLUTION -- it's difficult to show it hear with the code but if you go to this facebook forum post, you can read the solution      http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=69813

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the content that's hidden by visible-to-connection is hidden with CSS property `visibility:hidden` not `display:none` as you'd probably prefer.  So the content doesn't show up, but still takes up space in the page.

You can use CSS to move your content up.  Try wrapping your non-like content in

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thx for confirming this.  Sometimes things are so simple that I completely overlook them ;)